# Understanding Lang’s comment about Galois extensions under isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

I am reading Serge Lang’s Algebra chapter 6 ,(Galois Theory),section 1(page 264) and I didn’t  understand how exactly did he find the homomorphism $\sigma$ highlighted on the picture .

[image]

[image]

Comment: $\sigma$ is an arbitrary element of the Galois group $G(K/k)$, and the map is the map $G(K/k)\longrightarrow G(\lambda K/\lambda k)$ given by $\sigma\longmapsto \lambda\circ \sigma\circ\lambda^{-1}$; the latter is a map from $\lambda K$ to $\lambda K$, and can be verified to leave $\lambda k$ fixed pointwise (since $\sigma$ is a map from $K$ to itself leaving $k$ fixed pointwise).

Comment: You can figure it out because it says that the map $\sigma\mapsto \lambda\circ\sigma\circ\lambda^{-1}$ "gives a homomorphism of $G$ into the Galois group of $\lambda K$ over $\lambda k$". That is, he is **defining** a map with domain $G$ (that is, $G(K/k)$) and image $G(\lambda K/\lambda k)$.